# gRPC is not support with spring-boot 3 . is it going to be deprecated?

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

I am planing to use gRPC for new microservice platform. I realised that I am not able to use gRPC with latest spring boot.

is it not a good idea to use gRPC for new application?

What are the issues with gRPC?

Comment: What makes you think it is deprecated? There are starters for gRPC that work with Spring Boot 3 AFAIK.